# Measuring link load time asynchronously with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

New to ajax and stackoverflow--how can I determine how long it will take to load links on my page using ajax in a Chrome extension? Currently, I'm running a function each time a url on my page is successfully reached, but I don't believe the start time accurately reflects when the page starts loading. Is there a way I can remedy this? How would I be able to effectively calculate the time it takes for a link to fully load?

```
var col = new Array();
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
    $("a").each(function(){     
    var temp = $(this).not("#next").attr("href");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(temp===undefined){
        return;
    }
    col.push(temp);
    var start = 0;
    $.ajax({            
    url:$(this).attr("href"), 
    beforeSend: function (request, settings) {
    start = Date.now();
    },
    success: function () { 
        var end = Date.now();
        console.log(temp);
        console.log(start)
    }, 
    error: function (jqXHR, status, er) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 404) { 
        console.log(temp);
            console.log("connection failed");               
        }
  } 
});
}
)}}
);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) or [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)?

Comment: this runs when i click the extension button (i hope i'm answering your question). chrome.browserAction.onClicked

Comment: i actually managed to figure it out. i created a separate function that calls its parameter as a function. I placed my ajax as the parameter, so i was then able to call Date.now() before ajax every time